# How to stop task in pararell foreach loop when exception occurs?

Tags: c#, task, parallel.foreach, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I need to know how to stop task in pararell foreach loop when exception occurs? If Foo1() thrown an exception DoSomeWork() should be cancelled.

Item class

```
class Item
 {
     public async Task DoSomeWork()
            {
                try
                {
                     await Foo1();
                     await Foo2();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Writeline(ex.Message);
                }
             }


    private async Task Foo1()
    {   
        try
        {
        //
        // some functionality
        //
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // If exception occurs, then how cancel Task DoSomeWork()
        }
    }

    private async Task Foo2()
    {   
        try
        {
        //
        // some functionality
        //
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // If exception occurs, then how cancel Task DoSomeWork()
        }
    }
}
```

and the ItemCollection class with Pararell.Foreach loop

```
class ItemCollection
{
     public void StartAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                IList<Task> il = new List<Task>();
                Parallel.ForEach(ListOfItems, t => il.Add(t.DoSomeWork()));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
            }
        }
}
```

How to use the CancellationToken property in this example?

Comment: Just do not catch the exception or if you want for logging purpose throw it again afterwards

Comment: Do you want to cancel all the other iterations of the loop too?

Comment: @svick No, only the task that throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee256691(v=vs.110).aspx

Before the loops starts:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
```

Inside the loop:

```
Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) =>
                {
                    // Do some work here
                    po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                });
```

From another thread, you can trigger the cancel event:

```
cts.Cancel();
```